# How can I disable the flash on a Fujifilm Smart Shot Supreme?

Tags: film, flash, camera-settings, fujifilm

I'm new to film cameras. How do I make the flash not go off when I take pictures with my Fujifilm Smart Shot Supreme? It seems to be automatic, so would I just hold down the flash part with my finger then take the picture? (the flash still happens but is sort of concealed when held down)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the camera and can't find the user guide from a cursory web search, but based on watching a [YouTube walk-through](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t47gd_fpibY), it looks like a pretty rudimentary camera with not many features. I guess indeed, holding down the flash to conceal it might be your only option.

Comment: Please note, that not all cameras like it when you block a function by force. Placing a finger in front of the flash might be the better option. If the automatic is not completely rudimentary, thius might lead to underexposed images. The flash usually has a reason.

Comment: The heat generated by the flash can also potentially melt things inside the camera if held down for several successive shots.